# How do I use expect in a specific selector?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I am studying automated tests with `capybara`, `cucumber` and `webdriver`

I'm doing tests with expect, and I usually use `expect(page).to have_selector('p', 'some cool text')` to find an element, but sometimes it happens to have more than one similar selector, and sometimes it ends up being loaded after a while.

To simplify what I'm trying to say I'm going to put together a html scheme to demonstrate what I'm trying to find.

```js
setTimeout(function(){

document.getElementById('alpha').innerHTML = 'some cool text';

 },3000)
```

```html
<p style="background: rgba(255,0,0,0.1)">This text will load 
<p id="alpha">Text to load after 3s</p>
<p style="background: rgba(255,0,0,0.1)">similar text that I don't want to find</p>
<p>some cool text</p>
```

I needed to know how to select only the first text to validate that the word `'some cool text'` was loaded, adding id or classes are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you've written doesn't do what you're expecting because you're just passing 'some cool text' as a parameter rather than as the text option. What you want instead is

```
expect(page).to have_selector('p#alpha', text: 'some cool text')
```

which will wait up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds for a p element with id of 'alpha' containing the text 'some cool text' to appear. By default `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` is 2 seconds, so if you have a lot of things taking 3+ seconds to occur on your page you may want to increase that. If it's only this one you can extend the maximum wait for a specific call by passwing the `wait` option

```
expect(page).to have_selector('p#alpha', text: 'some cool text', wait: 5)
```

Also - if I were you I'd use `have_css` rather than `have_selector` when you know you're using CSS

```
expect(page).to have_css('p#alpha', text: 'some cool text', wait: 5)
```